# How to enter numbers in Forth

Tags: forth

Is there something like `input` in Basic or `scanf("%d")` in C in Forth?

Probably it will be something like this:

```
200 buffer: buf
: input ( -- n ) buf 200 accept 
  some-magic-filter
  buf swap evaluate ;
```

The problem in the above code, is how to define a filter that will pass only numbers, but not any words, definitions, etc?

Comment: How do you define numbers in this context? Integers (that is what the C example suggests - %d is the format specifier for decimal integer)? [Real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number) ("floats")?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard specifies only a low level [`>NUMBER`](https://forth-standard.org/standard/core/toNUMBER) word to interpret integer numbers.
OTOH using `EVALUATE` to convert strings into numbers is a quick and dirty way. Either use it without checks (in the case of trusted input) or do not use it at all. Trying to filter the string before `EVALUATE` is a bad idea: it has cost of `>NUMBER` word itself and low reusing factor.

**NB:** neither `>NUMBER` nor `EVALUATE` detects numeric overflow.

In any case, your word to input a  single-cell integer can be defined something like:

```
: accept-number ( -- n )
  PAD DUP 80 ACCEPT ( addr u ) StoN ( n )
;
```

In the case of trusted input you can define `StoN` like

```
: StoN ( addr u -- x )
  STATE @ ABORT" This naive StoN should not be used in compilation state"
  DEPTH 2- >R
    EVALUATE
  DEPTH 1- R> <> IF -24 THROW THEN
  \ check depth to accept the single-cell numbers only
;
```

Otherwise (in the case of untrusted input) you have two choices: to rely on the specific words of a particular Forth system or to use some (perhaps your own) library.

I use the following lexicon to define `StoN`:

```
\ ---
\ The words from Substring Matching library
\ (where length is counted in address units)

: MATCH-HEAD ( a u a-key u-key -- a-right u-right true | a u false ) 
  2 PICK OVER U< IF  2DROP FALSE EXIT THEN 
  DUP >R
  3 PICK R@ COMPARE IF  RDROP FALSE EXIT THEN 
  SWAP R@ + SWAP R> - TRUE
; 

\ ---
\ The words from Literals interpreting library
\ (where prefix 'I-' is shortcut for Interpret)

: I-DLIT ( a u -- x x true | a u false ) 
  2DUP S" -"  MATCH-HEAD >R
  DUP 0= IF  NIP RDROP EXIT THEN 
  0 0 2SWAP >NUMBER NIP IF  RDROP 2DROP FALSE EXIT THEN 
  R> IF  DNEGATE THEN  2SWAP 2DROP TRUE
; 

: I-LIT ( a u -- x true | a u false ) 
  I-DLIT IF  D>S TRUE EXIT THEN  FALSE
;
```

After that `StoN` can be defined as:

```
: StoN ( a u -- x ) I-LIT IF EXIT THEN -24 THROW ;
```

The mentioned libraries can be found at GitHub:

- [Substring matching functions](https://github.com/ruv/forth-design-exp/blob/master/lexeme-translator/lib/string-match.fth) library
- [Resolvers](https://github.com/ruv/forth-design-exp/blob/master/lexeme-translator/resolver.stdlib.fth) example (for various lexemes)

Answer (score 3):

[Rosetta Code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Determine_if_a_string_is_numeric#Forth) suggests this code snippet, working with GForth 0.6.2, to determine if an input string is numeric:

```
: is-numeric ( addr len -- )
  2dup snumber? ?dup if
   0< if
     -rot type ."  as integer = " .
   else
     2swap type ."  as double = " <# #s #> type
   then
  else 2dup >float if
    type ."  as float = " f.
  else
    type ."  isn't numeric in base " base @ dec.
  then then ;
```

Comment: In the C example, %d is the format specifier for decimal integer. Thus the complication with floats may not be necessary.

Comment: By the way, [`snumber?`](https://github.com/forthy42/gforth/blob/e3e2d44fdf795674696399002d21e5215532c050/kernel-ec/int.fs#L162) is not a standard word, and even is not [documented](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/Concept-Index.html).

Comment: Actually **snumber?** is not yet documented, but from GForth [source](https://github.com/forthy42/gforth/blob/master/kernel-ec/int.fs) it is easy to figure out that it is a wrapper around **s>number?**.

Comment: @luigif, yes, and since it is not a standard word the corresponding **link should be mentioned** in your answer. And due to lack of this link in your answer I have written it in my previous comment :)

Answer (score 1):

I built a BASIC like #INPUT word for Camel Forth to give BASIC users something more familiar. It takes more than one might think. It starts with $ACCEPT which can be used to like input with a string variable or memory block.

The definition of NUMBER? here is for single ints only but it compiles on GForth. It outputs true if conversion is bad; the reverse of SNUMBER?

```
    DECIMAL
    : NUMBER?  ( addr len -- n ?)      \ ?=0 is good conversion
               (          -- addr len) \ bad conversion
               OVER C@ [CHAR] - = DUP >R     \ save flag for later
               IF 1 /STRING THEN             \ remove minus sign
               0 0  2SWAP >NUMBER NIP NIP    \ convert the number
               R> IF SWAP NEGATE SWAP THEN   \ negate if needed
    ;

    : $ACCEPT ( $addr -- ) CR ." ?  "  DUP  1+ 80 ACCEPT  SWAP C!  ;
  
    : #INPUT  ( variable -- )   \ made to look/work like TI-BASIC
              BEGIN
                PAD $ACCEPT        \ $ACCEPT text into temp buffer PAD
                PAD COUNT NUMBER?  \ convert the number in PAD
              WHILE                \ while the conversion is bad do this
                 CR ." Input error "
                 CR DROP
              REPEAT
              SWAP ! ;           \ store the number in the variable

\ USAGE:  VARIABLE X  
\         X #INPUT
```