# Forth: How to create a word that compiles other words until certain delimiter is found?

Tags: forth

I use Forth (namely [Swapforth](https://github.com/jamesbowman/swapforth)) to configure certain [hardware](https://github.com/wzab/AFCK_J1B_FORTH) via I2C. I have a word:

```
i2c1-send ( reg-address byte -- )
```

that writes a byte to the specific internal register of a certain chip.
The initialization sequence is quite long, and therefore implementing it as below is not vialable due to memory consumption.

```
: i2c1-init
   $1201 $10 i2c1-send
   $2130 $43 i2c1-send
   [...]
   $0231 $43 i2c1-send
;
```

I have created an implementation that creates a structure holding the length of the sequence in the first cell and triple bytes in the next cells. (Please note that i2c1-send is just a placeholder allowing you to test it without my hardware).

```
: i2c1-send ( reg_addr byte -- )
  \ It is just a placeholder to show what will be written in HW
  swap
  ." addr=" hex . ." val=" . decimal CR
;    

: i2c1: ( "<spaces>name" -- )
  create here $326e9 0 ,
  does> dup cell+ swap 
  @ 0 do 
    dup c@ >r 1+
    dup c@ 8 lshift swap 1+
    dup c@ rot or r> i2c1-send
    1+
  loop 
  drop
; 

: i2c1-def ( addr val -- )
  c, ( adr )
  dup 8 rshift c,
  255 and c,
;

: i2c1; ( -- )
  \ Make sure that i2c1: was used before
  $326e9 <> abort" i2c1; without i2c1:"
  dup cell+ here swap - ( first_cell length )
  \ Verify that the length is a multiple of 3
  3 /mod swap 0<> abort" illegal length - not a multiple of 3"
  swap !
;
```

With the above code you define the initialization list similarly:

```
i2c1: set1
  $1234 $11 i2c1-def
  $1521 $18 i2c1-def
  [...]
  $2313 $10 i2c1-def
i2c1;
```

But the memory consumption is significantly reduced (by factor of 2 in case of J1B Forth CPU).

However I dislike the syntax. I'd prefere to have something that would allow to define the initialization list just by numbers, until certain delimiter is found, like below:

```
i2c1-x: i2c1-init
  $1234 $11 
  $1521 $18 
  [...]
  $2313 $10 
i2c1-x;
```

I have created the word shown below:

```
: i2c-delim s" i2c1-x;" ;
: i2c1-x: create here 0 ,
  begin 
   parse-name
     2dup i2c-delim compare 0<> while
     evaluate \ We store the address later
   parse-name
     evaluate 
     c, 
     \ Now store the address
     dup 8 rshift c,
           255 and c,
  repeat
  2drop
  dup cell+ here swap - ( first_cell length )
  \ Verify that the length is a multiple of 3
  3 /mod swap 0<> abort" length not a multiple of 3"
  swap !
  does> dup cell+ swap 
  @ 0 do 
    dup c@ >r 1+ 
    dup c@ 8 lshift swap 1+ 
    dup c@ rot or r> i2c1-send 
    1+
  loop 
  drop
;
```

It works perfectly for short definitions:

```
i2c1-x: set2 $1234 $ac $6543 $78 $9871 $01 $3440 $02 i2c1-x;
```

But fails for longer ones that use multiple lines:

```
i2c1-x: set2 
   $1234 $ac
   $6543 $78 
   $9871 $01 
   $3440 $02
i2c1-x;
```

Is it possible to define `i2c1-x` so that it handles multiple lines, or do I have to use solution based on separate `i2c1:`, `i2c1-def` and `i2c1;`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is [`REFILL`](https://forth-standard.org/standard/file/REFILL) word to parse multiple lines.

```
\ Get the next name (lexeme) possibly from the next lines
\ NB: Use the result of parse-name-sure immediate
\ since it may be garbled after the next refill
\ (the buffer may be be overwritten by the next line).
: parse-name-sure ( -- c-addr u|0 )
  begin parse-name dup 0= while refill 0= if exit then 2drop repeat
;

\ Check if the first string equals to the second
: equals ( c-addr2 u2 c-addr1 u1 -- flag )
  dup 3 pick <> if 2drop 2drop false exit then
  compare 0=
;
```

It is a common approach to translate the input until some delimiter. A general function to perform this approach:

```
\ Translate the input till a delimiter
\ using xt as translator for a lexeme
2variable _delimiter
: translate-input-till-with ( i*x c-addr u xt -- j*x )
  >r _delimiter 2!
  begin parse-name-sure dup while
    2dup _delimiter 2@ equals 0= while
    r@ execute
  repeat then 2drop rdrop
;
```

There is a sense to also factor out the manipulation of 16-bits units into a library:

```
[undefined] w@ [if]
\ NB: little-endian endianness variant
: w! ( x addr -- ) dup 1+ >r >r dup 8 rshift r> c! r> c! ;
: w@ ( addr -- x ) dup c@ 8 lshift swap 1+ c@ or ;
: w, ( x -- ) here 2 allot w! ;
[then]
```

Also, a function to converting text into number should be in a library. Using `evaluate` for that is not hygienic. See example of [`StoN` definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51704398/how-to-enter-numbers-in-forth/51716890#51716890) in "How to enter numbers in Forth" question. A helper to convert the "$"-prefixed numbers may be found in your Forth-system.

```
\ dummy definitions for test only
: s-to-n ( addr u -- x ) evaluate ;
: send-i2c1 ( addr x -- ) ." send: " . . CR ;
```

The application code:

```
\ Translate the input numbers till the delimiter into the special format
\ (the code could be simplified using the quotations)

: i2c-delim s" i2c1-x;" ;

: translate-i2c-pair ( c-addr u -- )
  s-to-n
  parse-name-sure
  2dup i2c-delim equals abort" translate-i2c: unexpected delimiter"
  s-to-n c, w,
;
: translate-i2c-input ( -- )
  i2c-delim ['] translate-i2c-pair translate-input-till-with
;


\ Send data from the special format

: send-i2c1-bulk ( addr u -- )
  3 /  0 ?do
    dup c@ swap 1+
    dup w@ swap 2+ >r send-i2c1 r>
  loop drop
;


\ The defining word

: i2c1-x:
  create here >r 0 , here >r translate-i2c-input here r> - r> !
  does> dup cell+ swap @ send-i2c1-bulk
;
```

A testcase

```
i2c1-x: test
1 2
3 4
5
6
i2c1-x;

test
```

Comment: Thanks, adding your code and replacing "parse-name" with "parse-name-force" just fixes operation for multiline definition. However I can see one potential disadvantage of my "simplified" solution. The error reports in case of malformed list of transfers are delayed and more difficult to analyze. (In the first, more complex solution, one may add the data check functionality in the `i2c1-def` word). But of course you answer solves the problem shown in my question.

Comment: I updated the answer to show how your application code could be made simpler: factor out a library code, break into smaller definitions. In the case of malformed list the error can be only detected when the delimiter is reached (regardless of the implementation).