# Writing a text file into an array on Forth

Tags: arrays, text-files, forth, gforth

I have a text file, containing an array of numbers such as:

```
1 0 0 1 0
0 1 1 0 1
0 0 0 1 1
1 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
```

I have opened the text file with the following code:

```
variable file-id
: open_file ( -- ) \ Opens the text file
  s" c:\etc\textfile.txt" r/w open-file throw
  file-id ! ;
```

I have also created an array to store this data:

```
create an_array 25 chars allot \ Create the array

: reset_array ( -- ) big_array 25 0 fill ;
reset_array \ Set all elements to 0
```

Is there a way to write the contents of the text file into the array with Forth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 1. Lazy way

A lazy way is to just evaluate a file by performing `included` on the file name.

```
\ Some library-level common words
\ --------------------------------

\ Store n chars from the stack into the array at c-addr, n >= 0
: c!n ( n*x n c-addr -- )
  >r begin dup while ( i*x i )
    \ store top from i*x into addr+(i-1)*char_size
    1- tuck chars r@ + c! ( j*x j )
  repeat drop rdrop
;

\ Execute xt and produce changing in the stack depth
: execute-balance ( i*x xt -- j*x n ) depth 1- >r execute depth r> - ;

: included-balance ( i*x c-addr u -- j*x n )
  ['] included execute-balance 2 +
;

\ The program
\ --------------------------------

create myarray 25 chars allot \ Create the array

: read-myfile-numbers ( -- i*x i )
  state @ abort" Error: only for interpretation"
  s" ./mynumbers.txt" included-balance
;
: write-myarray ( i*x i -- )
  dup 25 <> abort" Error: exactly 25 numbers are expected"
  myarray c!n
;
: fill-myarray-from-myfile ( -- )
  read-myfile-numbers write-myarray
;
```

#### 2. Tidy way

A careful way is to
read a file (completely, or line by line), split the text into lexemes, convert lexemes into numbers, then store the numbers into your array.

See: [How to enter numbers in Forth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51716890/1300170) .

On a low level it can be done via [`read-file`](https://forth-standard.org/standard/file/READ-FILE) or [`read-line`](https://forth-standard.org/standard/file/READ-LINE), something like [`word|tail`](https://github.com/rufig/spf4-utf8/blob/master/devel/%7Epinka/samples/2005/lib/split-white.f) and [`>number`](https://forth-standard.org/standard/core/toNUMBER) (or something like `StoN` library word from the example above).

On a higher level: use Gforth specific words like `execute-parsing` or [`execute-parsing-file`](https://gforth.org/manual/The-Input-Stream.html), [`parse-name`](https://forth-standard.org/standard/core/PARSE-NAME) and [`s>number?`](https://gforth.org/manual/Line-input-and-conversion.html)

```
: next-lexeme ( -- c-addr u|0 )
  begin parse-name ?dup if exit then ( addr )
    refill 0= if 0 exit then drop
  again
;
: read-myfile-numbers ( -- i*x i )
  s" ./mynumbers.txt" r/o open-file throw
  [:
    0 begin next-lexeme dup while
      s>number? 0= abort" Error: NaN" d>s swap 1+
    repeat 2drop
  ;] execute-parsing-file
;
```

If you need to read too many numbers, you have to write them into the array one by one at once, instead of placing all of them into the stack.