# What is RDROP in Forth?

Tags: forth, gforth, win32forth

I'm new to Forth and I'm using SwiftForth. I am looking for a way to read a matrix from file as described here *[Writing a text file into an array on Forth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64370406/writing-a-text-file-into-an-array-on-forth)*, but `rdrop` is not recognised. Is this exclusive to Gforth or is it part of a library? If it's a library, what are the steps needed to use it?

Comment: DROP the top item on the return stack. `: rdrop  r> drop ;`

Comment: @TlsChris, your definition is incorrect.

Comment: @ruvim Whoops!  Don't post code you can't test.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RDROP` is a well known but not standardized word.

This word can be defined in the following way:

```
: rdrop ( R: x -- ) postpone r> postpone drop ; immediate
```

A conditional definition in a portable library can look like the following:

```
[UNDEFINED] RDROP [IF]
: RDROP ( R: x -- ) POSTPONE R> POSTPONE DROP ; IMMEDIATE
[THEN]
```

Comment: I'm using your LAZY WAY code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64370406/writing-a-text-file-into-an-array-on-forth and adding this rdrop definition on top of the Forth file and I created mynumbers.txt with the same matrix of 25 0s and 1s. I drag and drop both files and it runs correctly but the contents of myarray, reading with c@, are not what expected. Changing the numbers in the text file does not change the contents of myarray, which (when converted to ASCII) contains some words such as "Error" and "myfile" as well as random characters. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @phisquared, you shouldn't drag-n-drop the file with numbers `mynumbers.txt`. After loading the Forth file, you can perform `fill-myarray-from-myfile` or `s" mynumbers.txt" included-balance write-myarray`. To show the content of the array: `myarray 25 dump`.

Answer (score 0):

"rdrop" can also be defined as followed, although it is not strictly standards compliant:

```
: rdrop r> r> drop >r ;
```

This has the advantage that is can be used as an execution token and it will not attempt to compile words into the dictionary, although it will not likely do anything sensible.

Comment: A problem is that this variant doesn't work in many standard Forth systems. And even if it works, the phrase `' rdrop execute` might not work, so this execution token is useless. Thus a standard program is not allowed to obtain the execution token for a word with non default interpretation semantics.

Comment: Yeah, it might not work, but it might, the other one posted *will not* work as an execution token. I have also seen forth implementations that do not have postpone defined, nor do they have \[undefined\], \[if\] or \[then\] defined. I do not think one way is better than the other, it is nearly always useful to have many different implementations when it comes to Forth.